# Speeding up the performance of huge multiple queries statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, node.js, node-mysql

I have node.js script which is running as a cron job on the server.

It asyncronously receieves  the data from external sources (several sumultaneous requests) and  updates database with multiple queries statements where UPDATE queries are separated with semicolons.

One 8000-UPDATES multi-query runs about 55 seconds.

Is there the way to speed somehow up the total database updating process?

The single query is very simple - like

```
 UPDATE my_table SET field1 = smth WHERE id = some_id;
```

The index is created for *id* field.

Comment: Show us your queries, and you indexes, so we know the structure of the queries. How many queries are there?

Comment: Yeah I 2nd showing the queries, schema and number of rows per table, without that info its just guessing.

Comment: How many entries does the table have?

Comment: About several hundred of thousands

Comment: @zavg I think the length of the query is the problem. Such extremely long query needs a significant time to transfer to the database. I think splitting the queries to be sent one by one may speed up and reduce the memory usage a bit.

Comment: @Licson I have used the expeience from http://neatline.org/2012/11/28/populating-mysql-tables-with-node-js/ where guy describes that he insert 500,000 records in 10 sec using huge INSERT-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the number of queries performed is going to be your biggest win.  Perhaps an **INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**?

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, field1) 
    VALUES
        (1, 'smth'),
        (10, 'smth2'),
        (88, 'smth3'),
        (23, 'smth4'),
        (68, 'smth5')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        id = VALUES(id),
        field1 = VALUES(field1);
```